# ng-repeat doesn't display empty fields in table

Tags: angularjs

I use the ng-repeat to create a table. However, there are also empty fields in the table, which must also be displayed. AngularJS filters them out directly.

Can I work around this somehow?

[Heres a example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjpcE.png)

```
`<tr>
<td>{{ Ratios['A'] | currency }}</td>
<td>{{ Ratios['B'] | currency }}</td>
<td>{{ Ratios['C'] | currency }}</td>
<td>{{ Ratios['D'] | currency }}</td>
<td>{{ Ratios['E'] | currency }}</td>
<td>{{ Ratios['F'] | currency }}</td>
</tr>`
```

Some of these Ratios are empty, and when I now try to do this with a ng-repeat the empty fields were not displayed, but I like these also to be displayed.

Comment: What you mean empty fields you mean empty rows? can you post your model?

Comment: we could help you if you post your code

Comment: show your array with "Ratios", some of the values cannot be filtered with `currency` filter and so they will show up as empty values

Answer (score 0):

**Two options:**

**One:** Decorate currency filter like below:

```
app.filter('defaultCurrency', function($filter) {
return function(input, symbol) {
  input = input || 0;
  return $filter('currency')(input, symbol);
};
```

});

e.g.: https://plnkr.co/edit/MPi5u2JbgwuFa4fGU06Y?p=preview

**Two:** Use `|| 0` in your expression like:

```
<td>{{ (Ratios['A'] || 0) | currency }}</td>
```